# SocialSharing PhoneGap Plugin URL_NOT_SUPPORTED

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am using this plugin for sharing images on my Android Phonegap project.
https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin

To share an image I am calling plugin with these parameters

```
window.plugins.socialsharing.share('Title', null,'/data/data/com.example.app/images/myimage.jpg', null);
```

and then getting the below error:

> file:///android_asset/www/plugins/nl.x-services.plugins.socialsharing/www/SocialSharing.js:
>   Line 93 : The injected error callback of 'share' received:
>   "URL_NOT_SUPPORTED"

The image file that I am trying to share was created with Context.MODE_PRIVATE permission.

```
File myImageFile= new File(context.getDir("images", Context.MODE_PRIVATE), "myimage.jpg");
```

I doubt that one of these could be possible reason for the failure:

1. The plugin is not working because I am passing the image uri in wrong way?
2. The image is not visible to the plugin because it was created with MOD_PRIVATE

Answer (score 7):

I was having a similar issue and solved it by explicitly prepending the filepath with file://

```
if(application.isAndroid) {
   filePath = 'file://' + filePath;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for me. I am selecting a picture from the camera plugin and it returns a filename e.g. `/storage/emulated/0/Download/2092654-726a1905.jpg` after prepending with `file://` sharing this to whatsapp using `cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing` plugin works!